batchSize is not working in NLog.config file for NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage
I am using latest version of NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage
And in documentation the batchSize is mentioned

But when I am providing the batchSize lets say as 1000 it is taking same number of CommittedBlockCount as with default batchSize which is 100.
Am I missing something?
Here is my NLog.config file entry
<target
  xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage"
  name="azure"
  layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${machinename}|${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false}|${callsite:className=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=true}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
  connectionString="${gdc:item=BlobConnectionString}"
  container="azuresyncservice"
  blobName="${event-properties:environment}/Logs/Logs_${event-properties:customernumber}_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt"
  batchSize="10000"
  queueLimit="10000" />

And here is my code to log the lines
public void PrintLogs()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<= 50000; i++)
    {
        _logger?.Info("", $"print line no: {i}", null);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

Moreover, is there a way to add timeout value to push the logs to azure if the batch size is not completed yet and time is elapsed in NLog.config file?

See also: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/issues/155

You have to set TaskDelayMilliseconds to a high value as well, the default value is 200ms in this library. I was also confused about this but after some testing I found out that NLog will send the messages to the blob after this period regardless of the batchSize.
What batchSize does here is that groups the messages into fewer commits when it's actually sending the messages.
If you would have batchSize = 1 and TaskDelayMs = 10*1000 it would still send the messages once every 10'th second but it would still basically send them one by one.
Similarly if you have batchSize = 1000 and TaskDelayMs = 200 it would still send the messages it has got every 0.2 second so the batchSize isn't very applicable for this short interval unless you have a lot of messages every second.
